# Prove $\int_{0}^{\sin^2x}\arcsin(\sqrt{t})\, dt+\int_{0}^{\cos^2x}\arccos(\sqrt{t})\, dt=\frac{\pi}{4}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Prove that for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$, $\int_{0}^{\sin^2x}\arcsin(\sqrt{t})\, dt+\int_{0}^{\cos^2x}\arccos(\sqrt{t})\, dt=\frac{\pi}{4}$

I tried to simplifiy the integrals separately, using on the left integral the substitution $t=\sin^2u$ but it doesn't work out.

Comment: Add the $dt$ for clarification...

Answer (score 1):

Setting in the first integral $t=\sin^2 u$ and in the second $t=\cos^2u$ we have:
$$
\int_0^x 2u\sin u\cos u\,du+\int_x^{\pi/2} 2u\sin u\cos u\,du=
\int_0^{\pi/2} u\sin 2u\,du=\frac\pi4.
$$

Comment: thanks, my mistake was in the boundaries of the right integral.
what we do basically is saying $t=cos^2u$ therefore $u=arccos(\sqrt{t})$ and we activate this function on the boundaries of the original integral? making sure it is continuously differentiable on the relevant segment?
if not, could you elaborate on how you determine the boundaries?

Comment: @reggiN Yes, you got it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Call the left-hand side $f(x)$ so$$f\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\int_0^1\arcsin\sqrt{t}dt=\int_0^12u\arcsin udu=\frac{\pi}{2}-\int_0^1\frac{u^2}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}du=\frac{\pi}{4},$$where we can evaluate the last integral with $u=\sin y$. Further, $f^\prime(x)=2\sin x\cos x(x-x)=0$.